# How to add a file in shelved change list in Perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I edited a file and then shelved the changes in it with shelved changelist `X`. Now I edit another file. How can I add this file in already existing shelved changelist `X` or generate a new changelist containing changes in both files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You don't have to `unshelve`, as @Dennis suggests, although that may be one way to do it.

**For an unopened file you wish to add to an existing shelf,** simply open that file into your existing shelve's changelist. For example, if your shelf is identified by changelist #1729, then do

```
p4 edit -c 1729 forgot_to_shelve.py
```

Then, shelve it:

```
p4 shelve -c 1729
```

If it turns out that the file already exists in the shelf but you wish to update it, then as usual, add `-f`:

```
p4 shelve -c 1729 -f
```

**For a file that's currently opened that you wish to add to your existing shelf,** you would first `reopen` that file into your existing shelf's changelist, before shelving as above:

```
p4 reopen -c 1729 forgot_to_shelve_and_currently_opened.py
p4 shelve -c 1729
```

---

Reference:

> In order to add a file to a pre-existing shelve, the file must first be opened in the shelve's changelist; use `p4 reopen` to move an opened file from one changelist to another.

<sup>[p4 shelve // Perforce 2013.3: Command Reference](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r13.3/manuals/cmdref/p4_shelve.html)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can [unshelve](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/unshelve.html#1046500) the changelist to your client, add the file, and then [shelve](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/shelve.html) it again. It will keep the same changelist number as changelists are only renumbered (if required to [maintain chronological order](http://kb.perforce.com/article/781/changelist-renumbered-on-submit)) on submit.

Basically, think of a shelved changelist as a local pending changelist that you have just put aside for a moment.

Comment: I want to do it in already existing client from which I created shelved list. I am unable to create/update changelist containing changes in both files.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem. Why are you unable? Do you get an error? If so, please post it.